# Deploy contract in py-evm

Tags: py-evm

I have a pretty dummy contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.16;

contract Ballot {
    struct Voter {
        uint weight; // weight is accumulated by delegation
    }
}
```

Compiled with remix I receive the following bytecode:

```
{
    "linkReferences": {},
    "object": "60606040523415600e57600080fd5b5b603680601c6000396000f30060606040525b600080fd00a165627a7a72305820c9e69aabe54411b89c6b2223932d7349334d3e75c12657355b7ba52c47e4db250029",
    "opcodes": "PUSH1 0x60 PUSH1 0x40 MSTORE CALLVALUE ISZERO PUSH1 0xE JUMPI PUSH1 0x0 DUP1 REVERT JUMPDEST JUMPDEST PUSH1 0x36 DUP1 PUSH1 0x1C PUSH1 0x0 CODECOPY PUSH1 0x0 RETURN STOP PUSH1 0x60 PUSH1 0x40 MSTORE JUMPDEST PUSH1 0x0 DUP1 REVERT STOP LOG1 PUSH6 0x627A7A723058 KECCAK256 0xc9 0xe6 SWAP11 0xab 0xe5 DIFFICULTY GT 0xb8 SWAP13 PUSH12 0x2223932D7349334D3E75C126 JUMPI CALLDATALOAD JUMPDEST PUSH28 0xA52C47E4DB2500290000000000000000000000000000000000000000 ",
    "sourceMap": "26:104:0:-;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;"
}
```

I am trying to deploy it in a spurious dragon py-evm using the following code:

```py
SENDER_PRIVATE_KEY = keys.PrivateKey(        
   decode_hex('0x45a915e4d060149eb4365960e6a7a45f334393093061116b197e3240065ff2d8')
)

SENDER = Address(SENDER_PRIVATE_KEY.public_key.to_canonical_address())

state = chain_without_block_validation.get_vm().state
state.set_balance(SENDER, 1000)

vm = chain_without_block_validation.get_vm()
nonce = vm.state.get_nonce(SENDER)

vm_tx = vm.create_unsigned_transaction(
   nonce=nonce,
   gas_price=0,
   gas=3138525,
   to=CREATE_CONTRACT_ADDRESS, 
   value=0,
   data=b'60606040523415600e57600080fd5b5b603680601c6000396000f30060606040525b600080fd00a165627a7a72305820c9e69aabe54411b89c6b2223932d7349334d3e75c12657355b7ba52c47e4db250029', 
)
signed_tx = vm_tx.as_signed_transaction(SENDER_PRIVATE_KEY)
new_block, receipt, c = chain_without_block_validation.apply_transaction(signed_tx)
```

The problem is that I always receive the following outputs:

```
Computation is error: True
Computation error: Out of gas: Needed 1782022989126083463177950425152579434543167263616556917372498944687405603136755656096088332 - Remaining 3073463 - Reason: Expanding memory 0 -> 966588469268559010541288244128370517706469799232
code len: 24576
computation output: b''
computation output len: 0
```

Following the code I have observed that error happens in the opcode 55 (CALLDATACOPY) when evm tries to extend memory. it tries to extend from:

```
before_size = 0
after_size = 966588469268559010541288244128370517706469799232
```

with a gas cost:

```
after_cost = 1782022989126083463177950425152579434543167263616556917372498944687405603136755656096088332
```

Anyone that has successfully deployed a smart contract can provide me any help?

Thanks for advance. :-)

Comment: Please try setting gas price to 10 or so.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I didn't have access to my computer, I have tried with gas_price=10, same result...


Computation error: Out of gas: Needed 178202298912608346317795042515257943454316726361655691737249894

Comment: @Pave, any other suggestion?

Comment: The problem seems to be the python code I think. I have never used py-evm so I can't help you there.